# Shuffle function does not work using a pointer

Tags: c++

I recently started c++ and I created a class called `Deck` that pretty much creates a deck of cards. One of it's functionality is to shuffle a deck. I created a object of type `Deck` in `main()` and was able to called the `shuffle()` member function...which worked! However when I accessed the `shuffle()` function using a pointer, Xcode highlights:

```
Card u1 = *(cards[index]);
```

and outputs:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = EXE_1386_GPFLT)
```

Can anyone help me out here?

```
void Deck::shuffle()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    for(size_t x = 0;x<cards.capacity();x++)
    {
        int index = rand()%51;
        int index2 = rand()%51;

        Card u1= *(cards[index]);
        *cards[index] = *cards[index2];
        *cards[index2] = u1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Deck p;
    //p.shuffle(); //works!
    //p.Display();//works!
    Deck *p;
    p->shuffle(); //does not work!
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` and `std::shuffle`?

Comment: I think you've missed the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

### Pointer which points nowhere

```
Deck *p;
p->shuffle(); //does not work!
```

You've just created a pointer to a deck. Where is the actual deck to which the pointer points to?

You should do

```
Deck* p = new Deck;
p->Shuffle();
```

or

```
Deck theDeck;
Deck* p = &theDeck;
p->Shuffle();
```

### Iterate till size, not capacity

```
for(size_t x = 0;x<cards.capacity();x++)
```

You are not allowed to access all elements within the vector's capacity. You should use `x < cards.size()`

### Cards are not pointers, are they

Does your `cards` container hold pointers to cards? If it contains actual cards, not pointers to them, then your swap routine should not use dereferenceing (`*cards[index]` --> `cards[index]`)

### 52 cards, not 51

Incidentally, if `cards` had 52 elements, then you should `rand()%52`, not 51.